# Renaming Columns dynamically R

Tags: r, dataframe, rename

I am new to R (SAS programmer) and want to get out of the "loop" mentality.

Say I have the following columns in a `data.frame`:

```
1999, 1999_1, 1999_2, 2000, 2000_1, 2001_2, 2002, 2000_1, etc
```

what I'm trying to do is write a function that loops through and renames them like so:

```
1999_A, 1999_B, 1999_C, 2000_A, etc
```

Any ideas how to do this without a loop?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into the paste function. You will want to firs strip off the underscores from each of the column names by selecting on the first four characters of each column name. Then you will want to paste "_A" on the 1st, 4th, 7th, ... column. Then paste "_B" on the 2nd, 5th, 8th, ... column. Then paste "_C" on the 3rd, 6th, 9th, ... column. You can select which columns you want using indices, and you can set it to start at a value and have a lag of 3.

```
colnames(dataframe) <- paste(colnames(dataframe)[indices],"text here")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach.

```
library("gsubfn")
x<-c("1999","1999_1","1999_2","2000","2000_1","2000_2")
x<-paste(x,"_",sep="")
x
[1] "1999_"   "1999_1_" "1999_2_" "2000_"   "2000_1_" "2000_2_"

find_replace<-list("_" = "_A", "_1_" = "_B", "_2_" = "_C")
gsubfn(paste(names(find_replace),collapse="|"),find_replace,x)

[1] "1999_A" "1999_B" "1999_C" "2000_A" "2000_B" "2000_C"
```

In your case `x = colnames(df)`.